# How to split in string

Tags: arduino-mega, string

I want to split this:

```
char* value = "12;32;blue";
or
string value = "12;32;blue";
```

into this vars:

```
TV = 12;
AR = 32;
LED = "blue";
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C-strings (`char*`), your best option (in terms of performance and memory consumption) is to use [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

```
char* value = "12;32;blue";
char* token = strtok(value, ";");
int TV = atoi(token);
token= strtok(0, ";");
int AR = atoi(token);
token = strtok(0, ";");
char* LED = token;
```

**Note 1**: the code above takes it for granted that `value` is properly formatted, i.e. contains 3 parts split by `;`. If it is not sure, then you should add additional checks on `token` value returned by `strtok`.

**Note 2**: `strtok` is modifiying its `value` argument, so that at the end of the code above, `value` will not be equal to `12;32;blue` any longer.

**Note 3**: `LED` variable above will point directly to the character `b` inside `value`, which means that if `value` is modified afterwards, `LED` might be modified as well.

Answer (score 3):

Scan function should do the job.

```
int tv, ar;
char color[10];
sscanf(value, "%d;%d;%s", &tv, &ar, color);
```

Comment: That's a great old trick. I totally forgot about it! https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/216535/parsing-a-string-into-tokens-using-sscanf

Comment: I think you meant `sscanf` not `scanf` as the latter needs `stdin` which Arduino doesn't have. Also in your example you shouldn't pass `&color`, but rather `color`.

Comment: and where do i tell the sscanf to get val from my var 'value' ?

Comment: @Thiago: as first parameter. Corrected.